# Docker user authentication against LDAP over SSL

Tags: docker, daemon

I want to add Authentication and Authorization for the docker daemon for more security.

use case :-

Any command can be issued to the docker daemon by only valid user and that the user has the rights to execute the command. Here I want to use LDAP for user authentication.

Q :- Does docker has integration with LDAP for above use case ? If not then any work around to do this ?

I want help how to proceed on this. some starters will help.

Please advise me. Thanks for answer !

Answer (score 0):

One way to protect docker daemon is to give access to the socket file only to users who should have access. Docker uses a group called `docker`, so adding a user to this group gives access to all docker commands `gpasswd -a user docker`. This however does not restrict the commands a user can run.

If you'd prefer LDAP authentication and restriction on commands, take a look at [Docker remote API](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.21/) which is used internally by docker client as well. You can use it to control docker daemon, add your own authentication, restriction on commands, etc.