# need help in Docker Daemon authentication and authorization

Tags: docker, authorization, daemon

I am looking for adding more security to docker daemon.
Like my company have docker host running some where and all users of company trying to connect to docker host using docker client and doing some operations(docker run,docker build,docker pull,docker push,.... etc).

I want to add Authorization layer on top of this so that I can control users to perform this operation and control which user can perform what.

I would love to have LDAP as source to control auth mechanism but need some solution which can help to achieve with docker daemon.

Anyone knows how can I achieve this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33754278/docker-user-authentication-against-ldap-over-ssl/